# Como acessar os elementos de uma lista declarada numa classe diferente?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, método, return

Desenvolvi um código que gera uma lista quando os seguintes dados de entrada são informados:

- Tamanho da lista (ou quantos "*Indexes*")
- Os valores que preencherão os ditos "*Indexes*".

Os valores são coletados dentro de um método inserido na classe pública "*ListMethod*". Gostaria de poder acessá-los posteriormente após o preenchimento. Segue o código abaixo.

Declarando o método (fora do `Main()`)

```
public void GenerateList(int Length)
{   
         int count = 1;

         List<int> Numbers = new List<int> ();

          for(int c = 0; c < Length; c++)
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Qual é o {0}º número da lista?",count);
               Numbers.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadKey())
               count++;
          }
}
```

Usando o método (dentro do `Main()`)

```
        ListMethod insertList = new ListMethod();

        Console.WriteLine("Qual é o tamanho da lista?");
        int ListLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        insertList.GenerateList(ListLength);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel, o seu método

```
public void GenerateList(int Length)
```

tem uma problema importante. Pois a variável local `Numbers` nunca é usada, de fato. Ela tem uma memória alocada como uma `List<int>`, é atribuída uma `new List<int>`, e essa lista é populada pelo método. Porém com essa variável local, ou você a usaria dentro do próprio método, ou não há porque tê-la.

Pelo resultado que você deseja, de poder acessar a lista de fora da classe, há, ao menos, duas formas de alterar seu código para permitir isto.

**Primeira Forma**

A primeira já foi endereçada pelo Maniero: alterando a assinatura do método para:

```
public List<int> GenerateList(int Length)
```

e, completando o código dele, o corpo do método seria:

```
{   
    var numbers = new List<int>();
    for (int c = 0; c < Length; c++) {
        Console.WriteLine("Qual é o {0}º número da lista?",count);
        numbers.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    }
    return numbers
}
```

A questão aqui é o `return` fazendo que, quando você invocar o método de dentro de `Main`, a chamada retorne a lista. Logo, para você poder usar essa lista, seria apenas necessário você criar uma variável local em `Main`, e atribuí-la com o retorno do método `GenerateList`, assim (dentro de `Main`):

```
List<int> listaLocal = insertList.GenerateList(ListLength);
```

A partir daí você pode acessar essa lista como desejar.

**Segunda Forma**

Outra maneira de você poder acessar a lista criada pelo `GenerateList`, é declarar a lista como uma propriedade da classe `ListMethod`.

Assim, a classe `ListMethod` deveria se parecer com:

```
public class ListMethod
{
    ...
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
    ...

    public void GenerateList(int Length)
    {
        int count = 1;

        for(int c = 0; c < Length; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Qual é o {0}º número da lista?",count);
            Numbers.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadKey())
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Daí, sua chamada em `Main` seria a mesma de antes, e você poderia acessar a lista enquanto o objeto estiver dentro do escopo. Se a instanciação de `ListMethod` for de dentro de `Main`, você estará livre para acessá-la:

```
Main()
{
    ...
    insertList.GenerateList(ListLength);
    List<int> listaLocal = insertList.Numbers;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! O problema era a falta da keyword "public", com ela consegui que o método retornasse os valores da lista.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que retornar a lista para que o consumidor possa usar. Assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => ListMethod.GenerateList(5);
}

public static class ListMethod {
    public static List<int> GenerateList(int length) {
        var numbers = new List<int>(length);
        for (int c = 0; c < length; c++) {
            WriteLine($"Qual é o {c + 1}º número da lista?");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var number)) {
                WriteLine("Valor digitado errado, digite novamente");
                c--;
                continue;
            }
            numbers.Add(number);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rnx5zg). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hh49kE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnList.cs).

Note que na forma mostrada não faz sentido este método ser uma instância de uma classe. Não sei nem se precisa ser outra classe.

Se tiver algo que não está na pergunta que faça sentido ter uma instância, aí muita coisa precisa ser mudada, não basta isto.

Note que simplifiquei, otimizei e modernizei o código, além de verificar se a digitação foi bem sucedida para não deixar o programa quebrar. Quem sabe até poderia usar um *array* no lugar da lista neste caso.

Também consertei a leitura que é feita sempre com o `ReadLine()`, o `ReadKey()` serve para outra coisa e não funcionará como espera neste caso.

Tem outras coisas que possivelmente poderiam ser melhores, mas depende de contexto que não temos.

Quem sabe um `while` fosse melhor que um `for` neste caso.

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que você cria uma nova instância do ListMethod com a sua lista dentro você inicializa tudo do zero.

Depende muito do cenário, mas se voce quer preencher uma lista, e deixá-la em memória para sua aplicação consumir essa lista posteriormente (durante a execução) uma opção é você usar o [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)

Você cria um cache com uma Key e depois retorna ele através da mesma Key.
Adicione referência para:

> System.Runtime.Caching;

```
  var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
  var obj = new List<int> {1, 2};

  cache.Set("Key", obj, null);

  var lstfromCache = (List<int>)cache.Get("Key");
```